# Changing the app url inside a Laravel 4.2 Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I run a multi-tenant site built in Laravel 4.2. In the App config, I'm aware that you can set a single base URL, e.g.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://apples.local',
```

I've built an Artisan command to deliver scheduled emails to users, no matter which domain they access the site through. So the command needs to generate urls with a different domain, e.g. `http://oranges.local`.

In my command, I'm attempting to alter the `app.url` config variable before generating a URL, but it seems to have no affect:

```
Config::set('app.url', 'http://oranges.local');
$this->info('App URL: ' . Config::get('app.url'));
$this->info('Generated:' . URL::route('someRoute', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

Despite physically altering the config at runtime, this still always produces:

```
App URL: http://oranges.local
Generated: http://apples.local/foo/bar
```

The URL generator is completely ignoring the app config!

I know I can setup multiple environments and pass `--env=oranges` to Artisan, but in my use case this isn't really practical. I just want the ability to set the app url site-wide during runtime.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would it be practical to just get the route path from the URL generator (not the absolute path) and append the domain separately? `URL::route('someRoute', ['foo', 'bar'], false);` would just generate `/foo/bar`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had considered that also, but again the problem is my use case. Your suggestion works fine for urls that I generate myself, but I also use packages that generate their own urls, eg. https://github.com/iwyg/jitimage and these need to render the correct domain also, not just the default root url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, whoacowboy was right and the config is not being considered at all. What I've found is that the site's base URL (even in Artisan commands) seems to come all the way back from the Symphony Request object.

Therefore to change/spoof the domain inside Artisan, the following will work:

```
Request::instance()->headers->set('host', 'oranges.local');
```

It might be wise to revert the host name back again after you're done with the change, but at least in my use case, this has solved all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

[`URL::route()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php) calls `$route->domain()` which gets the domain from [`$route->action['domain']`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php)

```
/**
 * Get the domain defined for the route.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function domain()
{
    return isset($this->action['domain']) ? $this->action['domain'] : null;
}
```

So it doesn't look like it is using `Config::get('app.url')` to set the url.

benJ seems to have a good idea. Why don't you manually write the URL?

`$emailURL = Config::get('app.url') . '/foo/bar/'` and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To repeat my comment to benJ, this is a perfectly sound suggestion for urls that I write myself, but packages like iwyg/jitimage, which I use for resizing/caching images generate their own urls and they also need the correct domain. But yes, it may be that this will be a sacrifice I have to make ultimately.